# Sending emails from script - empty email

Tags: email, shell-script

I have some script that sending email to me from server:

```
#!/bin/bash
DWATYG=$(date +%d.%m.%Y -d '16 days ago')
RAPORT=$(ausearch -i -k RBS -ts $DWATYG)
echo "$RAPORT" | mutt -s "Raport RBS" my@email.com
```

This script launched from crontab. For every time I got empty email, without message body.
If I run this commands from command line everything is ok. What's the problem?

Comment: Try running the script from outside the directory it is located in (for example, navigate to /tmp and then call it from there with the full path). Does it run fine or generate an error?

Comment: No errors. Emails have report from ausearch tool. But if this script is runned from crontab emails are empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When used in a cron job `ausearch` needs the `--input-logs` option

From the man page:

```
--input-logs
    Use the log file location from auditd.conf as input for searching.
    This is needed if you are using ausearch from a cron job.
```

To get eventual error messages in your email you can redirect STDERR to STDOUT

```
RAPORT=$(ausearch -i -k RBS -ts $DWATYG 2>&1 )
```